# Existence of a set of matrices akin to Gamma matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Can anybody tell me whether it is possible to have a set of 4 complex $N\times N$ matrices:

$$A^\mu A^\nu + A^{T\mu}A^{T\nu} = \eta^{\mu\nu}I$$

Where $A^{T\mu}$ is the transpose of $A^\mu$, $I$ is the $N\times N$
identity matrix and $\eta^{\mu\nu}=diag(1,-1,-1,-1)$ is the Minkowski Metric.

Comment: What is $\eta^{\mu\nu}$?

Comment: I assume it is the Minkowski metric tensor, $\eta^{\mu\nu}=\text{diag}(1,-1,-1,...,-1)$.

Comment: I've added some clarifications

Comment: I am not sure what means $A^\mu$ and $A^\nu$. If they allowed to be arbitrary matrices, we can put $A^\mu=I$ and $A^\nu=\frac 12\eta^{\mu\nu} I$.

Comment: $A^\nu$ and $A^\mu$ can be arbitrary matrices, $A^\nu = \frac{1}{2} \eta^{\mu\nu}$ seems impossible to me since $A^\nu$ depends only on the index $\nu$ and $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ depends on two indices...